# Selecting from all available serial ports using Qt GUI

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qtgui

I could not find a conclusive answer to my issue so I decided to post my first question on this site. I'm fairly new to programming and have been using Qt for a couple of months now. 
My code communicates with a microcontroller via serial ports, however the available port differs from pc to pc. I'm displaying the number of ports available with the code;

```
qDebug() << "Number of serial ports:" << QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts().count();
```

My question is: how can I display the name of all the available ports eg `"COM 10, 17. 22, etc"` and then show them in my GUI. What I eventually hope to do is have a combo box that can be dynamically populated with the available ports, I have one that switches between a couple ports at the moment but these are fixed ports corresponding to particular computers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWindow>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QComboBox>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    w.resize(200,200);
    w.show();

    QComboBox box(&w);
    Q_FOREACH(QSerialPortInfo port, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
        box.addItem(port.portName());
    }
    box.move(100 - box.width() / 2,100 - box.height() / 2);
    box.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The code is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just posted a link in my answer that solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Found a relevant answer on qt centre, example code;

```
foreach (const QSerialPortInfo &serialPortInfo, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts())
    {
    ui->comboBox->addItem(serialPortInfo.portName());
    }
```

Comment: Could you summarize the content? StackOverflow doesn't like link-only answers. they suffer from link rot.